# E-mail failure notice greylisted by CYREN

Tags: web-hosting, email, spam

I am having some problems with e-mail and I hope somebody could explain me on which side is the problem. Last 14 days I received 2 rejected messages. I am not sure if the problem is on my hosting side or recipient.

First message:

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at sipuk.myhosting.net.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<lizg@domainname.com>:
RECIPIENT_IP does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 554 5.7.1 <lizg@domainname.com>: Recipient address rejected: 421 MY_WEBSITE_IP greylisted by CYREN GlobalView IP reputation
Giving up on RECIPIENT_IP.
```

Which IP is greylisted, sender or recipient?

Second e-mail:

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at sipuk.myhosting.net.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<mail@domainname.com>:
RECIPIENT_IP failed after I sent the message.
Remote host said: 557 An email address in the email contents matches known spam senders.
```

I am also not sure here, is the problem on my hosting or recipient?

Tnx!

Comment: Check your domain name(s) and IP address here: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx There are links to follow to know how to fix the problem. Blacklists and any other similar list are mostly IP address based, however, some domain name lists exist. As well, it is always the sender that is checked and not the recipient.

Comment: Don't forget that if you are on a shared server, it might not have anything to do with you.  Another customer may have been responsible (wittingly or not) for a spam event and the whole server may be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The second fail email tells you that an email address in the email matches a known spam sender, doyble check your email blacklist status using a site like mxtoolbox.com but from the logs you are showing the recipient might be blacklisted and the smtp server sipuk is configured not to send email to known spam senders.